# Dual y-axis in chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am trying to make a combo chart (bar and line). Usually, a simple way is to add a dual y-axis. However, sometimes this could be confusing. Recently, I came across some alternative options, and I was wondering if this would be possible to do this in excel. Please see the attached example. Thanks

[Possible options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4V9f.png)

Comment: It's quite interesting but if i'm not wrong practically not looking possible in Excel,,, but I can show you an alternative and finally it looks like ONE Chart,,, please confirm if this works for you through comments only !!

Comment: Excel chart cannot directly obtain these top and bottom structure charts, in my opinion, it requires stitching 2 charts.

Comment: After some practice, I realised it was not possible to do it in one chart but need to combine two charts. Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These can both be (rather) easily accomplished in Excel.

The first example is a basic combo chart (clustered column and line with markers), then formatted to taste.

[image: Combo Chart]

The second example is two charts (as noted by Emily).  Use Page Layout>Align>Snap to Grid to align the Chart and Plot Areas so the Axis are nicely aligned. Change the Border to No Line for a seamless experience (I only have it turned on to show the relative borders).

[image: Two Aligned Charts]

Answer (score 0):

**:Caveat:**

*Earlier I've mentioned throw comments that practically *Dual Y axis is not possible*, especially when scale have been adjusted for Employee.
Originally Employee's list has value from 82 to 110, and is been adjusted between 60 to 120.*

*In fact I was waiting for OP's confirmation, but unfortunately OP didn't turned back.*

***Solution posted by @dav has inspired me to post the method, which I've discovered & has advantages too.***

---

**Step 1:**

- Create *Clustered Bar graph* using range A83:C91.
- Select Bar & and by using *Format Data Series*, set the *Gap Width 30%*.
- Now for *Format Axis* for *Numbers* enter this `[>=3000]0;;;` & hit *Add*.
- Finally select the *Format Chart area* & for *Border* set *No Line* and
  from *FORMAT Tab*, Shape Outline set *No Out Line*.

**Step 2:**

- Now create *Line with Markers graph* using Range D83:D91.
- For *Format Axis*, Number use this `[>=80]0;;;` , *since 82 is the lowest value* & hit Add.
- For Line graph also for *Border* set *No Line* and from *FORMAT Tab* Shape
  Outline, *set No Out Line*.

**Step 3:**

- Place both graph one below others another, TOP is the *Line graph*.
- Adjust height & width of both graphs as suitable, try to  place the
  *Bar graph* as closer to the *Line graph*.

[image]

- Now by holding **Ctrl** button, select both graph & hit *FORMAT Tab* &
  hit *Bring Forward*, this will bring the *Bar graph* forward since has
  been overlapped by *Line graph* while place it as closer to the *Line
  graph.*
- Final one is, hit the **GROUP** command.

***This will convert bot graph into one object, and the biggest advantage is that non of the graphs will synchronize while handling them.***

---

**The Final Look**

[image]

---

**N.B.**

- Scale setting are adjustable.
- For the Revenue collected I've set the Scale `[>=3000]0;;;` because
  lowest value is 3000 and scale setting help user to place both graph
  as closer.

***Let me remind the Scale setting built in commands, Bounds & Units doesn't works as the above shown format, since the shown format adjusts the scale while using the full scale, and if you use builtin command then the scale will start from the lowest value.***